# Is there an application that aggregates forum posts, like “@threadreaderapp unroll” does for twitter?

Tags: forum

There is often very valuable information buried in long forum posts. E.g.

https://endless-sphere.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=30&t=93818

But the user interface is atrocious, given the quantity of posts, e.g. the above example has more than 200 pages of posts.

Is there any application that tames this mess? Something that just extracts the text, such as what "@threadreaderapp unroll" does for twitter, would be a huge improvement, but a collapsible reddit style interface would be even better. Any suggestions?